# Which nodes do I give the input to in a Liquid State Machine?

Tags: machine-learning

I’m trying to make a Liquid State Machine in python and I already read many articles about it, but still there are many points I don’t understand.

(I had trouble putting 'LSM's in context to see what it actually is, but looking at [PyBrain's feature](http://pybrain.org/pages/features) list and the description of [aureservoir](http://aureservoir.sourceforge.net/) I could classify LSM like this: 'Machine Learning' > Networks > Recurrent Networks (RNN) > Reservoir Computing > Liquid State Machine (LSM).)

However I don't understand how do I give the input to the liquid?

Should I give it to *all* the neurons, or just to a selected (how?) *few*, or only to *one*?**

Comment: It seems to me that this question is a part of the others you asked.

Comment: @Raphael I think it's reusing the text only in order to describe the liquid state machine, but it would be hard to merge this question into a single title with the others. They address different parts of the LSM.